# Multiple google domains and accounts

Tags: google-search-console

I have multiple domains and logins for Google, I have looked at the documentation for combining services like analytics, search and adsense but it is getting more confusing as I read more. Is there or should there be a single simple cheatsheet to help?
I thought this would help
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/
but doesn't link my other accounts
A single single control panel would help enormously - I might be doing something stupid but I dont want to struggle with something that should be obvious
Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use one Google Account for all the services ie:

- [Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics)
- [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)
- [Adsense](https://www.google.com/adsense/)